# C# Graphics DrawText on Transparent Window

Tags: c#, string, graphics

I have a small problem, and I can't seem to find any solution.

The Problem is: I want to draw text with the Graphics class onto a transparent window. The window was made transparent by making the window BackColor to some color and the transparencyKey to the same.

My Code:

```
    RECT rect;
    Graphics g;
    Font f = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 20);
    private void menu_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawString("Test: True", f, new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), 100,100);
    }
```

The thing is that the string will glitch out a little bit, and there are still pieces of the BackColor sticking to it:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0z7w.png)

Can anyone help me or does anyone know another method to draw String(s) on Transparent windows? Thank you :)

Comment: Turn off all anti-aliasing of the Graphics object, both in the SmoothingMode and in all theTextRendering properties! (Btw: Your code look a little as if you prepare caching the Graphics object. Don't even think of it!)

Comment: Thank you so much!